# Sorting an array of String objects on J2ME platform

Tags: java, string, sorting, java-me

What is the best(fastest) way to sort an array of Strings (using Java 1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`java.util.Arrays.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

If it's not possible for some reason due to limitations of the platform, you can get ideas from its source.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code for sort the string values,

```
public Vector sort(String[] e) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        for(int count = 0; count < e.length; count++) {
            String s = e[count];
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                int c = s.compareTo((String) v.elementAt(i));
                if (c < 0) {
                    v.insertElementAt(s, i);
                    break;
                } else if (c == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i >= v.size()) {
                v.addElement(s);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Also see this sample code for using bubble sort,

```
static void bubbleSort(String[] p_array) throws Exception {
    boolean anyCellSorted;
    int length = p_array.length;
    String tmp;
    for (int i = length; --i >= 0;) {
        anyCellSorted = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (p_array[j].compareTo(p_array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                tmp = p_array[j];
                p_array[j] = p_array[j + 1];
                p_array[j + 1] = tmp;
                anyCellSorted = true;
            }

        }
        if (anyCellSorted == false) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first function (insertion sort) is not actually a sort: it drops duplicates due to the `if (c == 0) break;` clause.